# Why does it say a file I have doesn't exist when I do git subtree push?

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

I used a monorepo structure for my [project](https://github.com/kurtispykes/Portfolio-Projects/tree/main/IEEE-CIS%20Fraud%20Detection). I'm not trying to deploy my API on Heroku with the CLI. When I do `git subtree push` from the top level of the working tree I get the following error:

```
'IEEE-CIS' does not exist; use 'git subtree add'
```

The directory clearly exist as you can see in my [project](https://github.com/kurtispykes/Portfolio-Projects/tree/main/IEEE-CIS%20Fraud%20Detection). I used `git subtree add` with no success. Here's the full command I'm using atm:

```
git subtree push --prefix=IEEE-CIS Fraud Detection/packages fraud_detection_api heroku main
```

Comment: Hint: shell split the command by spaces and passes the parts to `git`; so `git` receives `--prefix=IEEE-CIS` as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, spaces separate arguments. `IEEE-CIS` is being interpreted as the prefix, then `Fraud`, and `Detection/packages` are separate arguments.

Try quoting the argument:

```
git subtree push --prefix="IEEE-CIS Fraud Detection/packages" fraud_detection_api heroku main
```